# amsthm not working correctly with unicode-math

Tags: amsthm, unicode-math

I'm trying to use `unicode-math` with `amsthm`. I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}
        My question
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

The output produced looks like this:

```
? My question
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you compile it with XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: XeTeX from TeXLive 2013. Just also upgraded and tried with TeXLive 2014.

Comment: Just also tried with LuaTex. Same result.

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty big difference to what's expected! I've added this to the `unicode-math` list of issues to be fixed: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/271

Comment: @WillRobertson This has come up recently in another question: from memory, it comes down to the order in which things are done ant the fact that `question` is a rather generic name (plus of course that LaTeX2e uses the same namespace for environments and commands).

Comment: @JosephWright So that's it? Is there nothing I can do until the authors get around to fixing things?

Comment: @JosephWright ok you're right. I changed question to something else and now it displays fine. That is probably the most weird-ass bug I've ever seen. Thanks!

Comment: @WillRobertson thanks for filing the report!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unicode-math` somewhat bravely defines `\question` to be `?` you can restore your definition afterwards (or simply use a different name)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\let\savedquestion\question

\begin{document}
\let\question\savedquestion

    \begin{question}
        My question
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at this with fresh eyes, a fair few of these symbols should be renamed to be less problematic. (There is also `\atsign`, `\ampersand`, and so on which I'm not too comfortable "reserving" the definition.)

Comment: @WillRobertson just a suggestion but you might consider adding a namespace prefix to your symbol names. Something like `\uc_question`, `\uc_ampersand` etc.

Comment: @KG I have a couple of ideas on this. A global prefix isn't appropriate since most of these macros are intended to be user-accessible, such as `\times`, `\sum`, etc etc. However, there are a few ‘questionable’ choices of mine originally for these symbols that I've now renamed to `\mathquestion` etc.